# Why doesnt potential divide in parallel circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance

My initial question was why potential doesnt split in a junction in parallel connections. Say we have resistances R1 and R2 which are in parallel, and a cell that is in parallel with them. Let the junction between the resistances be A and B (Basically the simplest form of a parallel circuit). We know that the used up potential in these resistances has to be equal to the potential difference between A and B (conservation of energy) and that current is also conserved. But why does that have to imply that potential doesnt divide?

As far as I can see, we can divide the input current in junction A in such a way so that we get V1 = I1R1 and V2 = I2R2, such that I1 + I2 = I. Now let V1 < Va - Vb and V2 > Va - Vb. can we not pick V1 and V2 in such a way that when the remaining potentials in the parallel wires meet up again at B and then disperse the energy among themselves, they again attain per unit charge energy of Vb? Then I arrived at an answer that well, if V2 > Va - Vb, then Va - V2 < Vb, which would imply that there is a potential difference within the ideal wire between junction B and somewhere after resistor R2, which I promptly concluded to be a contradiction. But why is it? What exactly would be the problem?

If we continue with this thought experiment, then we get that the potential after resistor R1 is greater than Vb and after R2 is less than Vb. So according to Ohm's law, infinity current would flow from B to 'after R2' and from 'after R1' to B. My guess was that this would defy conservation of current law. But if such infinity current flows in a loop, that would not defy conservation of current?

Im sorry if my phrasing was confusing, its my first question. I would appreciate if someone explained this to me. I guess my main question is where the error is in my understanding of the situation.

Comment: There can only be one potential at a point (junction) once a reference point is assigned. You can't "split" it.

Comment: could you elaborate on what a reference point is?

Comment: The point that is assigned a potential of zero. Though technically arbitrary, in a battery circuit it is typically the negative terminal of the battery . Then all potentials are measured with respect to that point

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned [Kirchoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws)'s current law, that current is conserved, but there is also Kirchoff's voltage law, that the directed sum of the potential differences around any closed loop is zero. This forbids alternate voltage divisions of the sort you describe.

To get an intutive grasp of Kirchoff's laws, it's useful to think of a physical analogy. If you imagine water flowing down a hill, the charge is analogous to the mass or volume of water, the current is analogous to the rate of flow, and the potential is analogous to the *height* of the water, measured from some defined zero level. If you dig two channels from A to B, the height drop along each of them has to be the same. If you walk around any closed loop, you can go up and down hill along the way, but the height changes have to add up to zero. When you get back to your starting position, you must get back to your original height. Situations like the [Escher Waterfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_(M._C._Escher)) are impossible.

Kirchoff's laws are based on a number of simplifying assumptions/approximations that are usually accurate in circult design. But there are situations where the assumptions are violated, and the laws don't work.

In the idealised case of wires with no resistance, it would indeed be possible to have current circulating in loops. A superconducting loop can sustain a circulating current indefinitely. But if the wire has any non-zero resistance, and without any external source of energy to drive it, such currents are quickly dissipated into heat. This situation still obeys Kirchoff's laws - the potential is constant all the way around the loop - but no longer gives a unique solution. The current in the loop can be arbitrary.

You can also get current flowing in closed loops by electromagnetic induction. A changing magnetic field induces a current in a closed loop of wire through which it passes. In this case, the idea of currents being driven by a simple scalar potential function doesn't work. If you deduce the voltage by multiplying current by resistance, you find that when they meet up again the voltage has to be higher after going round one side of the loop, and lower going round the other side. You can't make them match up. You can't walk around a closed loop back to your starting point going down hill all the way. In this situation, we need a more sophisticated version of the potential.